# RavenDb returns bad request could not figure out what to do at second API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I encountered an issue while developing and debugging .NET Web API using embedded RavenDb as my database and IIS express. 
First call to API executes normally and returns all results. There are no exception on that call. However, any consecutive call causes 400 - bad request response with body containing error text: "Could not figure out what to do". Error is repeatable, but you have to restart the API in debugger.

To connect to RavenDb, I have created my own controller that inherits from ApiController:

```
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Embedded;
using Raven.Database.Server;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

public class RavenController : ApiController {

    #region Declarations

    private static readonly Lazy<IDocumentStore> LazyDocStore = new Lazy<IDocumentStore>( () => {
        var docStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
            ConnectionStringName="RavenDB" 
        };
        docStore.Initialize();
        return docStore;
    } );

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IDocumentStore Store {
        get { return LazyDocStore.Value; }
    }

    public IAsyncDocumentSession Session { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Overridden methods

    public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync( 
        HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken ) {
        using (this.Session = this.Store.OpenAsyncSession()) {
            var result = await base.ExecuteAsync( controllerContext, cancellationToken );
            await Session.SaveChangesAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This controller is presented as a sample on RavenDb site.

The connection string is defined as:

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="DataDir=~\App_Data\albumDB"/>
```

WebAPI controller looks like this:

```
using Raven.Client;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

public class AlbumsController : RavenController {

    #region Public methods

    // GET api/Albums/GetAllAlbums
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAllAlbums() {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
        try {
            var albums = await Session.Query<Album>().ToListAsync();
            msg = Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK, albums );
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            msg = Request.CreateErrorResponse( HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex );
        }
        return msg;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And Album class is defined as:

```
public class Album {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }

}
```

I have googled around, but found nothing that would make any sense to me. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 400 request would indicate that you are running over HTTP, but your code is using embedded. Which one are you using?

Comment: I have not installed RavenDb on my PC. I have used nuget embedded package. Also, my connection string points to folder. Thus, I am assuming that I am using that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a working config for ravendb embedded:

in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            InitializeDocumentStore();

        }

        public static IDocumentStore Store { get; private set; }

        private static void InitializeDocumentStore()
        {
            NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8282);
            Store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ravenhost"]),
                Conventions = { IdentityPartsSeparator = "-" },
                Configuration = { Port = 8282 }
            };
            Store.Initialize();

        }
```

in Base Api  controller:

```
public IAsyncDocumentSession Session { get; set; }

        public async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
            HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (Session = WebApiApplication.Store.OpenAsyncSession())
            {
                var result = await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
                await Session.SaveChangesAsync();

                return result;
            }
        }
```

in your Apicontroller:

```
public async Task<BaseResponse<DocumentState>> GetById(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            _answer.SingleResult = await Session.LoadAsync<DocumentState>(id);
            _answer.Success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _answer.ErrorResponse = ex;
        }
        return _answer;
    }
```

ignore the _answer stuff, this is my custom return type.  however this works great local, and also works great when published to azure.

as a final note, my web config contains this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Raven/Port" value="8282" />
    <add key="ravenhost" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: notice that this IDocumentStore Store is created in global, once when run, not on the controller on every request